# Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://api.razorpay.com" from accessing a frame with origin "file://"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, payment-gateway

**I am integrating Razorpay inside my ionic application** , I have checked the documentation and implemented the same inside my application. **I am able to test the Wallet functionality and it's working fine and providing me payment_id as per expected** but **when I am doing payment** via **credit-card and  NetBanking**, it giving me above mentioned error.

I added all the required meta tags inside my index.html , here is the meta tags which I declared in index.html :-

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
 content="default-src 'self'  'unsafe-eval' https://*.razorpay.com https://www.handikart.co.in/ https://maps.googleapis.com https://code.jquery.com ;  data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport"
 content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

And when I tried to uninstall the plugin and re-install it, just to give a another try, Then my Main.js file start giving me error.

It's saying the following imports can not be resolved :-

```
import com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity;
import com.razorpay.Checkout;
import com.razorpay.PaymentResultWithDataListener;
import com.razorpay.PaymentData;
```

PaymentResultWithDataListener can not be resolved so do I need to add any Library or jar in my project ?

After reinstall the plugin version has been updated to **0.14.0** :-

**com.razorpay.cordova 0.14.0 "RazorpayCheckout"**

Seems now I do require Razorpay jar file in order to resolve this error.

**I even tried with fresh project but still getting import issues on adding plugin**.

**Steps followed in creating new project** :-

```
Ionic start RazorPaySample
cd RazorPaySample
ionic platform add android
then at last i added the plugin :-
cordova plugin add com.razorpay.cordova --save

My ionic version is :- 1.7.14 
My Cordova version is :- 6.5.0

 Java version :-
 java version "1.7.0_80" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
 1.7.0_80-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

**I found this link** :-

https://docs.razorpay.com/page/android-sdk-v013x

**it's razorpay-android.jar of version 0.13.0 By placing this inside my lib folder i am able to solve the two import file issues that are of** :-

`import com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity;
import com.razorpay.Checkout;`

**But still getting Import issue for** :-

`import com.razorpay.PaymentResultWithDataListener;
import com.razorpay.PaymentData;`

So is there any one who ever faced this issue, Any help would be great Appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally , It start working , the problem is plugin is outdated for eclipse , so i import the project in android studio and every thing starts working fine. I contact with their support team and they provide me this solution here is their comments :-

> The Android plugin for Eclipse is outdated and will not work for
>   gradle based projects. That is the reason you are getting import
>   errors in Main.java. You should be using Android Studio as an IDE for
>   the android part of your cordova project.